# How do I add UIImageViews to IBOutletCollection?

Tags: objective-c

I have an IBOutletCollection that holds UIImageViews. I would like to programmatically add more UIImageViews to that IBOutletCollection.

Here's what I have:

```
    IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imgs;
```

Thanks!

Comment: The whole point of having `IBOutletCollection` is to add items visually, not programmatically. You shouldn't need to add items to `IBOutletCollection` dynamically - you should be better off with your own mutable array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *tmpImages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.imgs];
[tmpImages addObjectsFromArray:@[ smth1, smth2, smth3 ]];
self.imgs = tmpImages;
```